# Help identify 8-pin SOIC chip with markings 1734 6M 2W4

Tags: identification, eeprom

I came across this chip, which is used for resetting toner page count. Could anyone identify its type?

[image: photo of PCB showing unknown IC]

Comment: toner page count?????

Comment: What do you want to know about it? You can find the complete module by searching for "Y404S" and it's described as "toner reset chip".

Comment: It’s a SAMSUNG p/n not found elsewhere, so imagine the cheapest Korean EEPROM <=1kB I2C chip

Answer (score 5):

Research indicates that a lot of these "toner chips" are nothing more than I2C EEPROMs.

It is clearly an I2C device, so you can find it's address using a microcontroller to scan the I2C bus.

A lot of these EEPROMs work the same way.

This github repo has code and information on how these EEPROMs are generally used in printers:

https://github.com/lugu/toner_chip_reset

If you have a working printer, you can also sniff the I2C bus to see what data is transferred between the chip and printer. The above github link has information on how to do that.